# want to fethch value in hidden field from dropdown in js

Tags: javascript, c#

From ddlCountryName dropdown i want fetch value in hdnCountryCode

```
function getWorkCenter() {
    debugger;
    var SelectedCountryCode = $('#ddlCountryName').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "FocussedMktBenefit.aspx/GetWorkCenter",
        data: '{"sPlant":"' + SelectedCountryCode + '"}',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var jsonProcessDetails = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data.d));    
        },
        error: function (Result) {
            alert("Error with AJAX callback");
        }
    });
}
```

---

Data also coming from .cs page using FocussedMktBenefit.aspx/GetWorkCenter but how to get in hidden field is problem.

Comment: Isn't `ddlCountryName` a drop down list? What kind of value are you expecting from `var SelectedCountryCode = $('#ddlCountryName').val();`?

Comment: Ah nevermind, it's a `select`-element

Comment: Could you explain what `hdnCountryCode` is, is it an input-field? Or maybe post some HTML?

Comment: hdnCountryCode is hidden field in which i want to store data which is come from  url: "FocussedMktBenefit.aspx/GetWorkCenter",  this function.

Comment: If the hidden field has an id of `hdnCountryCode`, couldn't you just use $('#hdnCountryCode').val();`?

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="hdnCountryCode" style="display:none;">
    <option value="123">aaa</option>
    <option value="456">bbb</option>
</select>
```

do you mean this ?

Comment: <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountryName" runat="server" CssClass="multiselect form-control" onchange="getWorkCenter();"></asp:DropDownList>                                       
             <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnCountryCode" runat="server" />

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to do something like this.

```
var jsonProcessDetails = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data.d));
$("hdnCountryCode").val(jsonProcessDetails);
```

Or if you are on aspx page and your Hidden field is `runat="server"` then

```
var jsonProcessDetails = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data.d));
$("[id$=hdnCountryCode]").val(jsonProcessDetails);
```